# In MNE-python, why is the power data scale from time-frequency representation (tfr) different from power spectral density (PSD) ？

Tags: matlab, mne-python, eeglab

When I managed my EEG data, the results of mne.time_frequency.tfr_morlet (or the other two methods) were an array of power around 1e-7. When being plotted with dB = 'True', a good graph was got only when the scale of color is around -150 to -200. However, when I did the psd analysis, the power is around 0-40. What made the differences? Besides, I also did time-frequency analysis with eeglab on matlab, the color scale of dB is around -40 to 40. I cannot understand the differences. Who can explain it, thanks.

[The tfr of MNE-python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXJfD.png)

[The psd of MNE-python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoCc3.png)

[The tfr of eeglab(matlab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHo8s.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is "why is the PSD different from the time-frequency power?" The PSD does not report based on time.

The time-frequency analysis shows you WHEN different frequencies appear in your data, whereas the PSD gives you the average power of the frequencies within your epoch.  At least, from my understanding.

You added 2 images of tfr output and 1 image of psd output--so I assume you are comparing the 2 tfr outputs to the 1 psd output.